# After MiKTeX update: suddenly all fonts (incl. existing path-referenced ttf files) are not found by fontspec / LuaLaTeX anymore

Tags: fonts, errors, luatex, miktex, fontspec

I just updated my MiKTeX packages (and also did FNDB refreshes, `updmap` and everything and also already tried a complete fresh install), but now I suddenly get loads of errors telling me that my fonts are not found, for example:

```
fontspec error: "font-not-found" The font "Philosopher-Regular" cannot be found.
```

At first I thought that some packages are missing because of the November Package Refactoring (https://miktex.org/alert/package-refactoring-2016-11). But for some of my fonts this can't be the reason, because I load some font files like this, which also triggers this error:

```
\newfontfamily\PhilosopherRegular[Path=../]{Philosopher-Regular.ttf}
```

And these files are in my git repository (and it compiled just fine before the update on the exact same code).

What ways do I have to attack this error?

Comment: You can reinstall the font as a system font and compile with `xelatex`.

Comment: Are you using luatex? If so, did you rebuild the luatex font cache? The MikTeX update FNDB and and styles does not do that for you. Easiest wasy to rebuild the cache is to find it and trash it.

Comment: @Bernard What If I have Lua code? Is XeLaTeX able to parse it just like LuaLaTeX?

Comment: which luatex version do you have now?

Comment: @Foo Bar: No, I don't think so.

Comment: @RobtA Where is the cache on Windows + MiKTeX?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.0 (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)`

Comment: Don't you get an error from luaotfload? what is your luaotload version?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `Package: luaotfload 2016/06/16 v2.7 OpenType layout system

 FATAL ERROR
 Luaotfload requires a Luatex version >= 0.95.0.
 Please update your TeX distribution!`

Comment: Ahhh: https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/382

Comment: get the prerelease https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/releases. use the tds.zip, unpack it somewhere outside miktex and add the root folder as a new root with miktex settings. When luaotfload is updated in miktex you can remove this root again.

Comment: Will I also get it when fetching updates from MiKTeX-Next repositories? This would seem more clean. But if not possible then I'll do the manual way.

Comment: No as luaotfload hasn't been updated on ctan miktex can't do anything about it. But adding the tds.zip as a new root is easy and easy to undo later.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. If you sum it up as an answer I will accept it. :)

Comment: @FooBar I'm not sure where the luatex font cache is on Windows, because I use the "portable" version there, and where I put it probably is not where the regular installation puts it. Look for a folder named "luatex-cache" which might be in your User AppData (hidden folder in Windows).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The current luaotfload on CTAN doesn't work with luatex 1.0 now used by miktex. As a work-around:

Get the prerelease of luaotfload https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/releases. Use the tds.zip, unpack it somewhere outside miktex and add the root folder as a new root with miktex settings. When luaotfload is updated in miktex one can easily remove this root from miktex settings.

Comment: @Crowley the official luaotfload works fine currently in miktex. I have no idea what problem you can have, the problem from this question is long gone.

Comment: I've found out that I dont have the font at the first place. My problem was a fasle alarm, sorry for bothering you.