# lm fonts not found by LuaLaTex

Tags: fonts, luatex, compiling, fontspec, latin-modern

When I try to compile a document using LuaLaTex, like in the following MWE, I obtain errors indicating me that Latin Modern fonts are not found. 
It is strange since I use only the most basic setup for LuaLaTex and the last updates for all packages involved.

Here is the MWE :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}%
\usepackage{luatextra}
% Can be replaced by : 
%\RequirePackage{fontspec}
%\RequirePackage{luatexbase}
%\RequireLuaModule{lualibs}
%\RequirePackage{metalogo}
%\RequirePackage{luacode}
\begin{document}

Qu'il s'agisse de technologie ou d'objets du quotidien, les verres sont partout dans notre vie courante. 
Il est impossible d'évoquer les verres sans évoquer les récipients que nous utilisons tous quotidiennement pour boire, où encore les vitres nous permettant de voir et de simultanément nous protéger des éléments extérieurs, que ce soit au bureau, à la maison où dans un véhicule. 

\end{document}
```

Here are the errors I get :

```
Font \EU2/lmr/m/n/10=file:lmroman10-regular:script=latn;+trep;+tlig; at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad
Font \EU2/lmr/m/sl/10=file:lmromanslant10-regular:script=latn;+trep;+tlig; at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad
Font \EU2/lmr/m/it/10=file:lmroman10-italic:script=latn;+trep;+tlig; at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad
Font \EU2/lmr/bx/n/10=file:lmroman10-bold:script=latn;+trep;+tlig; at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad
Font \EU2/lmss/m/n/10=file:lmsans10-regular:script=latn;+trep;+tlig; at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad
```

Additionnally, every character in the file is generating such error :

```
Missing character: There is no Q (U+0051) in font nullfont!
```

Here are the versions informations for the different components used :

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.0 (MiKTeX 2.9.6200 64-bit)  (format=lualatex 2017.1.1)  1 JAN 2017 18:48
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9r>
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
Package: expl3 2016/11/21 v6760 L3 programming layer (loader)
Package: expl3 2016/11/21 v6760 L3 programming layer (code)
L3 Module: l3bootstrap 2016/06/13 v6596 L3 Bootstrap code
L3 Module: l3names 2016/10/13 v6722 L3 Namespace for primitives
L3 Module: l3basics 2016/09/01 v6696 L3 Basic definitions
L3 Module: l3expan 2016/08/19 v6684 L3 Argument expansion
L3 Module: l3tl 2016/08/19 v6692 L3 Token lists
L3 Module: l3str 2016/08/19 v6692 L3 Strings
L3 Module: l3seq 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 Sequences and stacks
L3 Module: l3int 2016/09/07 v6700 L3 Integers
L3 Module: l3quark 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 Quarks
L3 Module: l3prg 2016/08/18 v6679 L3 Control structures
L3 Module: l3clist 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 Comma separated lists
L3 Module: l3token 2016/09/01 v6695 L3 Experimental token manipulation
L3 Module: l3prop 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 Property lists
L3 Module: l3msg 2016/08/19 v6691 L3 Messages
L3 Module: l3file 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 File and I/O operations
L3 Module: l3skip 2016/08/19 v6692 L3 Dimensions and skips
L3 Module: l3keys 2016/09/21 v6711 L3 Key-value interfaces
L3 Module: l3fp 2016/11/21 v6761 L3 Floating points
L3 Module: l3box 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 Experimental boxes
L3 Module: l3coffins 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 Coffin code layer
L3 Module: l3color 2016/06/13 v6596 L3 Experimental color support
L3 Module: l3sys 2015/09/25 v6087 L3 Experimental system/runtime functions
L3 Module: l3candidates 2016/08/19 v6688 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
L3 Module: l3luatex 2016/08/18 v6679 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
File: l3pdfmode.def 2016/08/18 v6679 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
Package: xparse 2016/11/21 v6760 L3 Experimental document command parser
Package: fontspec 2016/02/01 v2.5a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Package: luaotfload 2016/06/16 v2.7 OpenType layout system
Lua module: fontspec 2016/02/01 2.5a Advanced font selection for LuaLaTeX.
Package: fontspec-luatex 2016/02/01 v2.5a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Package: fontenc 2016/06/19 v1.99m Standard LaTeX package
File: eu2enc.def 2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
File: eu2lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
File: xunicode.sty 2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many other characters in Unicode lower plane
File: t3enc.def 2001/12/31 T3 encoding
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
Package: graphics 2016/07/10 v1.0t Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
File: luatex.def 2016/08/17 v0.01g Graphics/Color for luaTeX
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
Package: luatexbase 2015/10/04 v1.3 luatexbase interface to LuaTeX 
Package: ctablestack 2015/10/01 v1.0 Catcode table stable support
Lua module: lualibs 2016-04-06 2.4 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2016-04-06 2.4 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended collection.
Package: metalogo 2010/05/29 v0.12 Extended TeX logo macros
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
Package: luacode 2012/01/23 v1.2a lua-in-tex helpers (mpg)
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package: pdftexcmds 2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
Package: ifpdf 2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
```

If I remove the fontspec package, I don't get these errors, but fontspec is kind of essential to lualatex !

A few weeks ago, the same file was compiling well, and now, nothing works. 
I have spent the whole afternoon trying to find solutions and nothing helped ... I am kind of freaking out right now.

What can I do to get around this issue and get my document to compile again ?

I might add that I am working on a 150 pages document, so starting everything from scrap is not an option.

Comment: Apparently you just switched over to luatex 1.0. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337543/after-miktex-update-suddenly-all-fonts-incl-existing-path-referenced-ttf-file

Comment: Ohhhh !!! This did the trick ! I will flag my question as duplicate ! Thank you so much !!!

Comment: did you not get an error about the luatex version? (the old luaotfload should have done that?)

Comment: I don't think I did. Or it was burried under the errors, since every single character in the document was giving an error. The document shouldn't have tried to compile in these conditions anyway, and ideally, lualatex should have never gone live with the new version knowing that there would be no realeased version compatible for the luaoftload package at that time.